# Error: Module not found AngularJS+NodeJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, module, syncfusion

I'm trying to "*import*" a module instaled by *npm*. The module is *"syncfusion-javascript"* and it's downloaded and saved in the package.json correctly but when I try to use it with the *require* command it fails and shows me the next error : ' Error Cannot resolve module 'syncfusion-javascript' in App.js.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing ?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly try require('syncfusion-javascript/Scripts/ej/web/ej.grid.min.js'); instead of require('syncfusion-javascript'); to overcome the reported issue.

Comment: Thanks, It's solved. But now the error is ejPager not a function, there is a way to import all the libraries ??

Comment: Try require('syncfusion-javascript/Scripts/ej/web/ej.web.all.min.js');

Comment: Still giving the same error, and if I try to add some property to the 
`<div ej-grid e-datasource="data" e-allowsorting="true" e-allowfiltering="true">`.
Like `e-filtersettings="filterType"` gives me the next error **ejDialog(...) is not a function.**